# Showing Folder's modified date as most recently edited documents's modified date in that folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, folder, last-modified-date

I have a document library and a folder in it. And inside that folder, many documents are there.

Is it possible to show the folder's modified date as the modified date of the most recently edited documents in that folder ?

Comment: I beleive by default it shows the date of the last modified document

Comment: No @Red, By default it shows the date when any of the folder property was modified. Kindly try once editing the document inside a folder and see if folder's modified date changes or not.