# How can I make the 'modified date' column of a list reflect when the contents of folder were last modified, not the folder itself?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am using SharePoint online for work.  I have a subsite with 2 WebParts, both of which are lists (XsltListViewWebPart).  Each list has folders, with each folder having a number of documents within.

I'd like the 'modified' date on the list with the folders to reflect the date that the most recent item within that folder was modified, not the date the folder was modified (meaning if I chose to re-name it or something).

I have done many searches, and the most closely related post I've found is here:
[Showing Folder's modified date as most recently edited documents's modified date in that folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190950/showing-folders-modified-date-as-most-recently-edited-documentss-modified-date)  ...And it has gone unanswered for 3 years.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SP Online much, so this is by no means a definitive "I've had experience doing this, and this is how it's done" answer, but doing a little brainstorming, off the top of my head, I'd say...

Does it need to be the actual folder's Modified field?  Why not make a new date/time field called "Contents Modified" or something like that, create a Flow that's triggered when things are modified, and if a document is modified, set the parent folder's "Contents Modified" value to be the current date/time?  Or make it set the parent folder's "Contents Modified" value to be the current item's "Modified" value.  Something like that.

And then show that column in the view, and not the folders' actual Modified column.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Per my knowledge, it's impossible to change the behavior.

As a workaround, we could add a separate column (custom_modified_date) to the document library and whenever a file is added/updated trigger a flow and update the date in your custom modified date column.