# Default Value for Date and Time filed in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, administration, date-time

Is it possible to set the default value of a date and time field to the Modified date?

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you need the copy of the modified column? Why can't you just use the Modified column itself? Unfortunately, it is not possible to use other columns in "Default value" option of the column settings.

Comment: I have a document set content type and every time I modified the docset I want the document have the same modified date. at the moment documents have different modified date than docsets.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, this is not possible using calculated value option of column settings or calculated column formulas as you cannot get the date from parent folder/document set. Check my answer below.

Comment: Check these if it helps: [1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269192/how-can-i-make-the-modified-date-column-of-a-list-reflect-when-the-contents-of), [2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-and-onedrive-date-created-modified-vs/e18328b3-9e54-4289-8b45-77347974e492) and [3](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-folder-quot-modified-quot-date-not-accurate/m-p/3835344).

Comment: Hi @Harris, does my response below answers your question related to having "Calculated value" using formula?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use other columns in "Default value" formula/setting of the column in SharePoint.

[image]

**Additional**: The `TODAY` and `ME` functions are not supported in calculated columns but are supported in the "default value" setting of a column.